# Blender game engine development directions?

Tags: game-engine

I know that the these forms like to have questions that can be nicely answered, and I might be slightly passed that line... But anyway, what are the blender game engine development ideas? Is it still a part of the main focus of development? Or is it just a side feature that is worked on now and then.

I read the recent patch notes, and some nice new features has been added, but will it (or is it already) get on/close the same level as the mainstream engines? e.g. Unity, Unreal, or Cry.

I ask this because the posts/articles I've read about the blender engine is quite outdated, 3 or 4 years old, and I want to know how the blender engine is standing relative to other engines out there today.

Answer (score 4):

Ton Roosendaal covers this in the [Blender roadmap – 2.7, 2.8 and beyond](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/)

> What should then be dropped is the idea to make Blender have an
>   embedded “true” game engine. We should acknowledge that we never
>   managed to make something with the portability and quality of Unreal
>   or Crysis… or even Unity3D. And Blender’s GPL license is not helping
>   here much either.

If you want to develop a game today you can model assets with blender, but should better pick another game engine.

Comment: So... Still the same huh, I'll stick to using blender for modeling then :D.

Comment: no, you can not do an AAA game on an INDI engine, blender is very unstable, it does not have good documentation and it is as reliable as wikipedia, I like blender - yes, but it is a hippy-minded development, unable to mature a version to a degree of stability worthy of competing with other 3D engines, that should give you an idea of what can be done in game engine, I suggest you try with Ketsji Game engine,

Comment: I work only modifying bge, but as I do it alone, I'm very slow, I included a very small and simple particle system but still has too many bugs, and because of my work schedule I can not dedicate full time, if you are interested and you know something about c ++